# Searching data from table by passing table name as a parameter in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle9i

Is this stored procedure in oracle is correct for searching data from table by passing table name as a parameter

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE bank_search_sp
(
    p_tablename  IN  VARCHAR2,
    p_searchname IN  VARCHAR2,
    p_bankcode   OUT VARCHAR2,
    p_bankname   OUT VARCHAR2,
    p_dist_code  OUT NUMBER
)
AS
    v_tem VARCHAR2(5000);
BEGIN
    v_tem := 'SELECT bankcode,bankname,dist_code FROM ' || UPPER (p_tablename) || '
    WHERE bankname LIKE '''|| p_searchname||'''';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_tem
       INTO p_bankcode,p_bankname,p_dist_code
      USING p_searchname ;
END bank_search_sp;
```

Comment: Beware that `p_searchname` is not escaped in any way. What if I search for `Bob's bank`? Use `DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_LITERAL`, and also use `=` instead of `LIKE` if you don't want percent sign and underscores to have a special meaning.

Comment: as @Benoit said you should be carefull with this. I'd check that the p_tablename exists in

Answer (score 1):

If you need this procedure, then I guess that you have several tables with the columns `bankcode`, `bankname` and `dist_code`. If this is true, then try to normalize your model if possible.

---

The `USING` term is the correct approach, but you have to use the parameter in your query.

To avoid SQL injection, you could use [`dbms_assert.sql_object_name`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_assert.htm#BABDDEEF).

This should work for you:

```
v_tem := 'SELECT bankcode, bankname, dist_code FROM '
         || dbms_assert.sql_object_name(p_tablename)
         || ' WHERE bankname LIKE :1';
```

Your `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` will throw an exception when finding no row or more than one row, so using `LIKE` might not be a good idea.

---

Questions that you should ask yourself:

- Is the model properly normalized?
- Do you really need to use `LIKE`, or is `=` what you want?
- If you want to use `LIKE`, how should the program deal with `NO_DATA_FOUND` / `TOO_MANY_ROWS` exceptions?

Comment: This solution is still open to a SQL injection attack, as the contents of p_tablename are still used to generate the SQL statement.

Comment: @MikeMcAllister: You are right, fixed my answer. Guess I was just hoping that the OP would refrain from using this query at all...